# simple Kivy DropDown errors with 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'bind'

Tags: python, python-2.7, user-interface, kivy

I have been using `kivy 1.7.2` on Ubuntu 14.04 for some time; very easy to use and `kv` language makes design a breeze....

...except the DropDown has proven near impossible to setup without running it with `kv` and even has issues when initiated with more python code.

Here is what I start with....

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
from kivy.uix.floatlayout import FloatLayout
from kivy.uix.button import Button
from kivy.uix.dropdown import DropDown


kv_text = """#:kivy 1.7.2
<MyWidget>
    DropDown:
        id: menupanel
        on_parent: self.dismiss()
        on_select: lambda: None
        Button:
            id: button_a
            size_hint_y: None
            text: "A"
        Button:
            id: button_b
            size_hint_y: None
            text: "B"
    Button:
        id: button_opendd
        pos_hint: {"top":1, "right":1}
        on_release: root.ids.menupanel.open(self)
        text: "open"
"""

class MyWidget(FloatLayout):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(FloatLayout, self).__init__(**kwargs)

class MyWidgetApp(App):
    def build(self):
        return MyWidget()

def main():
    Builder.load_string(kv_text)
    app = MyWidgetApp()
    app.run()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

...
....which produces this error....
...

```
 Traceback (most recent call last):
   File "wtfkivy.py", line 60, in <module>
     main()
   File "wtfkivy.py", line 57, in main
     app.run()
   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/kivy/app.py", line 577, in run
     root = self.build()
   File "wtfkivy.py", line 52, in build
     return MyWidget()
   File "wtfkivy.py", line 48, in __init__
     super(FloatLayout, self).__init__(**kwargs)
   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/kivy/uix/layout.py", line 61, in __init__
     super(Layout, self).__init__(**kwargs)
   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/kivy/uix/widget.py", line 163, in __init__
     Builder.apply(self)
   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/kivy/lang.py", line 1429, in apply
     self._apply_rule(widget, rule, rule)
   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/kivy/lang.py", line 1531, in _apply_rule
     child = cls(__no_builder=True)
   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/kivy/uix/dropdown.py", line 160, in __init__
     self.container.bind(minimum_size=self._container_minimum_size)
 AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'bind'
```

The DropDown's `self.container` is supposed to default to a `GridLayout` but somehow that doesn't happen when set up via `kv` file.

I have gotten around this error by changing `DropDown:` in the kv to `MyDropDown:` and putting the `<MyDropDown>:` definition below everything. Then, in the python, I had to add the class with a `super(MyDropDown,self).__init__()` However! It just put a duplicate set of widgets into the dropdown. Woops? (If I change that init to `__init__(**kwargs)`, I end up with the same bind error. Huh?)

I have honestly scoured the internet numerous times for good examples of `DropDown` set up mostly via `kv`, but nothing that really hit the mark.

Even if the implementation in python worked out (with `super(`), it would not be preferred. I need the DropDown's widgets to be able to access attributes of the main app widget.

So the question: is there either a way to implement a DropDown almost entirely in `kv` (which makes design so clean and accessible) or something else that still makes the main app widget accessible?

**EDIT**
As indicated by *FJSevilla* and verified by testing, DropDown is broken in version 1.7.2. I added an answer to elaborate, since many others may be using the version supplied from their distro.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`DropDown` (and maybe other widgets) are broken in `Kivy 1.7`. DropDown specifically does not initiate properly from `kv` code.

If anyone needs to use a version this old, implement dropdowns using python alone and not kv (and expect trouble):

```
dd = DropDown()
b1 = Button(text="a")
b2 = Button(text="b")
dd.add_widget(b1)
dd.add_widget(b2)
```

Or try getting the kivy you wanted by *upgrading* to at least `1.9.x`. (I did not test 1.8.)
First off, if you use an older distro, you will probably have to upgrade kivy beyond what your distro provides.

On Ubuntu 14.04:

```
sudo apt-key adv --keyserver keyserver.ubuntu.com --recv-keys A863D2D6
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:kivy-team/kivy-daily
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install python-kivy python3-kivy
```

Note that this upgrade seems to change certain behaviors (read: new errors)...

First change...

For DropDown, `on_parent:self.dismiss()` was a bound attribute on the DropDown itself. After upgrading, this caused the DropDown to immediately dismiss itself on open. (You see it flicker for only a split-second.)

If you now encounter this error, moving `menupanel.dismiss()` (substituting your `id` in place of `menupanel`) to the root widget alleviated that problem.

Second change...

Somehow, having the `menupanel.dismiss()` OR `self.ids.menupanel.dismiss()` on the root widget was breaking the refs to the dropdown (essentially deleting the strong refs / getting garbage-collected) and causing this:

```
     on_release: menupanel.open(self)
File "weakproxy.pyx", line 30, in kivy.weakproxy.WeakProxy.__getattr__ (kivy/weakproxy.c:1145)
File "weakproxy.pyx", line 26, in kivy.weakproxy.WeakProxy.__ref__ (kivy/weakproxy.c:1069)
ReferenceError: weakly-referenced object no longer exists
```

(NOTE: The only time I see this error on the interwebs are for named classes (i.e. `class MyButton(Button)` that are instantiated by `kv` code. This is just a normal generic DropDown, so why cause an issue here?)

The solution, if you receive *that* error, is to add a reference to your DropDown instance...anywhere, to any object, when instantiated or in the function where the DropDown is opened. It just has to happen before the other reference is removed. (In my case, getting removed while switching to new `Screen` and back.)

```
class ...
    def ...
        self.backup_reference = self.ids.menupanel
```

Why? I have no idea.

....Or, if your DropDown was going to be very simple, try using [1](https://kivy.org/docs/api-kivy.uix.spinner.html) `Spinner` instead.

Answer (score 1):

The use of `DropDown` in Kivy-language is not too intuitive. However, it is possible to create your own DropDown menu using kv-language only:

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.uix.floatlayout import FloatLayout

kv_text = """\
#:kivy 1.7.2
<MyWidget>
    Widget:
        on_parent: menupanel.dismiss()

    DropDown:
        id: menupanel
        on_select: button_opendd.text = '{}'.format(args[1])

        Button:
            text: 'A'
            size_hint_y: None
            height: 30
            on_release: menupanel.select('A')

        Button:
            text: 'B'
            size_hint_y: None
            height: 30
            on_release: menupanel.select('B')

    Button:
        id: button_opendd
        pos_hint: {"top":1, "right":1}
        text: 'Press'
        on_release: menupanel.open(self)
        size_hint_y: None
        height: 40
"""

class MyWidget(FloatLayout):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(MyWidget, self).__init__(**kwargs)

class MyWidgetApp(App):
    def build(self):
        return MyWidget()

def main():
    Builder.load_string(kv_text)
    app = MyWidgetApp()
    app.run()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

> **Warning**: This code is tested in Kivy 1.9.3 and Kivy 1.10.0, i don't know if it will be backwards compatible with version 1.7.

If you put `on_parent` event inside `DropDown` instance the code run in Kivy 1.9 correctly but fail in Kivy 1.10 (menu is always hidden).

Running example:

[image]

Comment: That code suffers the same exact error in 1.7.2. Am I to assume that this is an error in the version distributed by Ubuntu 14.04?

Comment: @MookiBar, surely it is a compatibility problem with 1.7 version. Kivy 1.7 is already quite old (2013), do you have any reason not to upgrade to Kivy 1.10 or 1.9?

Comment: so the problem is entirely related to version. Unfortunately, short of trawling all the changelogs, I couldn't find a spot where "feature y is broken before version x.x" seeing that, IMHO, they put out a broken DropDown. Still, I upvoted your answer, not because it worked for my purposes, but because it's a good general reference...and that sweet graphic. (Sorry, SO-staff, if that is improper)